# How not to show a label under a graph using subfloat -- restart numbering of labels

Tags: beamer, numbering, captions, subfloats

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\graphicspath{{/folder/images/}}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Graph1}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Under the graph it shows me a label , "a". How can I not show it? Also, how to restart numbering of labels because the subfloat numbers all the figures from the beginning of the document?

Comment: Just use `\subfloat{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Graph1}}` without the optional arguments.

Comment: @Werner:!!And i was deleting only one []..Thanks!Also,how to start over numbering the labels?Because it is numbering all the subfloats from the beginning of the document.And ,could you make this an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) provides a number of different inputs to its `\subfloat` macro. It's usage results in different captioning styles. From the [`subfig` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) (Table 2 of section **2.2.1 The `\subfloat` Command**, p 4):

[image]

So, the only way to have a `\subfloat` without a caption is to use it as `\subfloat{<stuff>}` and remove *both* possible optional arguments.

`\subfloat` numbering, by default, is renewed with every `figure` environment. However, you can control the counter number by means of setting the `subfigure` counter. For example, `\setcounter{subfigure}{4}` will make your `\subfloat`s be numbered from `(e)`.